# how to count number of items per second in spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I get a json stream and I want to computer number of items that has a status of "Pending" every second. How do I do that? I have the code below so far and 1) I am not sure if it is correct. 2) It returns me a Dstream but my objective is to store a number every second to cassandra or queue or you can imagine there is function `public void store(Long number){}` .

```
  // #1
 jsonMessagesDStream
        .filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(String v1) throws Exception {
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            JsonObject jsonObj = parser.parse(v1).getAsJsonObject();
            if (jsonObj != null && jsonObj.has("status")) {
                return jsonObj.get("status").getAsString().equalsIgnoreCase("Pending");
            }
            return false;
        }
    }).countByValue().foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaPairRDD<String, Long>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(JavaPairRDD<String, Long> stringLongJavaPairRDD) throws Exception {
            store(stringLongJavaPairRDD.count());
        }
    });
```

Tried the following: still didn't work since it prints zero all the time not sure if it is right?

```
     // #2
    jsonMessagesDStream
        .filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(String v1) throws Exception {
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            JsonObject jsonObj = parser.parse(v1).getAsJsonObject();
            if (jsonObj != null && jsonObj.has("status")) {
                return jsonObj.get("status").getAsString().equalsIgnoreCase("Pending");
            }
            return false;
        }
    }).foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(JavaRDD<String> stringJavaRDD) throws Exception {
            store(stringJavaRDD.count());
        }
    });
```

part of the stack trace

```
16/09/10 17:51:39 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: count at Consumer.java:88
16/09/10 17:51:39 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 17 (count at Consumer.java:88) with 4 output partitions
16/09/10 17:51:39 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 17 (count at Consumer.java:88)
16/09/10 17:51:39 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
16/09/10 17:51:39 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
16/09/10 17:51:39 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 17 (MapPartitionsRDD[35] at filter at Consumer.java:72), which has no missing parents
```

BAR gets printed but not FOO

```
//Debug code
jsonMessagesDStream
        .filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(String v1) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("****************FOO******************");
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            JsonObject jsonObj = parser.parse(v1).getAsJsonObject();
            if (jsonObj != null && jsonObj.has("status")) {
                return jsonObj.get("status").getAsString().equalsIgnoreCase("Pending");
            }
            return false;
        }
    }).foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(JavaRDD<String> stringJavaRDD) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("*****************BAR******************");
            store(stringJavaRDD.count());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already filtered the result-set, you could just do a count() on the DStream/RDD.

Also I dont think you would need windowing here, if you are reading from the source every second. Windowing is needed, when the micro-batch interval doesn't match with the aggregation frequency. Are you looking at a micro-batch frequency of less than a second?

> It returns me a Dstream but my objective is to store a number every second to cassandra or queue

The way Spark works is it gives a DStream every time you do a computation on an existing DStream. That way you could easily chain functions together. You should also be aware of the distinction between transformations and actions in Spark. Functions like filter(), count() etc. are transformations, in the sense that they operate on a DStream and give a new DStream. But if you need side-effects (like printing, pushing to a DB, etc.), you should be looking at Spark actions.

If you need to push DStream to cassandra, you should look at cassandra connectors which will have functions exposed (actions in Spark terminology) that you can use to push data into cassandra.

Comment: Hi Thanks for that response! I actually want to write a message to a Queue (which btw is not Kafka) but can you imagine there is a public void store(Long number){} which will write a single number to queue. so can you tell me how the code would look like if I were to call this store function every second?

Comment: You could use foreach on the stream and call the function inside the lambda block.

Comment: but this DStream(a series of RDD's) represent data that it accumulated after one second so shouldn't I be doing count on the entire DStream ?Also when you say for each do you mean forEachRDD right?

Comment: A DStream is a continuously updating data-structure. Every time your micro-batch runs, it will have new elements. So if you need counts every second, you could set batch interval to 1 second and count the number of elements. And yes, I meant foreachRDD on the DStream.

Comment: Yes so my batch interval is one second (something that I pass in when I create a spark context). I have updated the code do you think that is right? Now that you said A DStream is a continuously updating data-structure does it produce one RDD every second or multiple RDD's every second? If it provides multiple RDD's every second then my code above would be wrong so thats the confusing part.

Comment: I added forEachRDD and took out window operation as you suggested

Comment: The code above prints zero all the time even though I deliberately pass the same message with status=="Pending" over and over in a tight loop. Does the code above looks correct?

Comment: Number of RDDs per DStream depends on the source and blockinterval. but generally, you shouldn't be worried by the underlying data-structure. Your code looks very correct, one thing you can check is if the filter function is returning false for all cases? Or it is returning true, yet the rdd's count is 0 in foreach?

Comment: Which code looks correct? #1 or #2? I assume  #2 and looks like it is not entering the filter stage(I had a print statement on the very first line of the  filter stage and it doesn't print) and I have edited my question with a part of the stack trace that may be useful. However, it is entering forEachRDD stage and I was able to see some print statements from there

Answer (score 1):

You can use sliding window of 1 second along with reduceByKey function irrespective of batch interval. Once you choose the 1 second slide interval you will receive a event for store call every second.

Comment: you mean .window(new Duration(1000), new Duration(1000)).reduceByKey() ? no filter ? or you mean .window(new Duration(1000), new Duration(1000)).filter().reduceByKey() ?

Comment: Not sure how that would look like?

Comment: @user1870400, Forget about the reduceByKeyAndWindow function, As you need only count value then you can use the countByValueAndWindow function as show below:



       `filteredDstream.countByValueAndWindow(Durations.seconds(5),  
Durations.seconds(1)).foreachRDD(new 
VoidFunction<JavaPairRDD<String, Long>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(JavaPairRDD<String, Long> 
stringLongJavaPairRDD) throws Exception {
                store(stringLongJavaPairRDD.count());
            }
        });`

Comment: @user1870400, In the above comment the filteredDstream is the stream generated after applying the filter function.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for this but isn't this count the values from the previous window? because all I am looking for number of events that match a certain criteria at second1, second2, second3......so on

Comment: Yeah, If you use the different values for the window duration and slide interval then it will count the values from previous windows. You can use fixed window by providing same value(1 seconds) for window duration and slide interval. Then it will generate only current window value by every second.

Comment: That's perfect!